# Rails 3 Extremely Large Model Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working on a Rails 3 application that has a form that takes one parent object with a couple of pre-defined attributes selected from a fairly large array.  Each parent object has several child objects that depending on which pre-defined attributes you have selected in the parent, can have WILDLY different min-max values, each with their own separate often unique limitations.

I am quickly realizing that validating these objects is going to result in an extremely large model file.  I was wondering if there was a proper way to remove this type of large scale validation from the model(or at least have the model point to somewhere else).

Also a more higher level question, is it normal to have a say... 1000 lines of code to validate the integrity of the data of an object?

Comment: Definitely not "normal" to have 1000 lines of validation code in your model.

Comment: Well I guess normal isn't the correct term.  A better term would be plausible.  I know for most things where you can use helper methods and maybe 1 custom helper(such as validating an email address) a few lines will do.  However what I am working on has a lot of little details that vary uniquely based on what you have selected.  So in order to catch every little case it seems like the code is going to bloat up pretty quickly.  Hence why I am trying to move it out of the model.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can create a custom validator class, which involves inheirting from ActiveModel::Validator and implementing a validate method that takes the records to validate:

```
class Report > ActiveRecord::Base
  validates with MyValidator
end

class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
 def validate(record)
    record.errors[:base] = << "Error" unless is_valid(record)
  end
end
```

2) In rails 3, there are validation macros as wel, which means extending ActiveModel::EachValidator:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name :report_like => true
end

class ReportLikeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value["Report"]
      record.errors.add attribute, "Does not appear to be a ..."
  end
end
```

Comment: For these custom validator classes where should I put them in my rails app?  Some places I read recommended the lib directory, but only once I put the code in the model did even my simple validations work.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/